# http.responseText не понятно что выводит

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть загрузка с формы через php ajax mysqli/
в js файле есть след код

```
/* ---------------------------- */
/* XMLHTTPRequest Enable */
/* ---------------------------- */
function createObject() {
    var request_type;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
       request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return request_type;
}
var http = createObject();


/* -------------------------- */
/* INSERT */
/* -------------------------- */
/* Required: var nocache is a random number to add to request. This value solve an Internet Explorer cache issue */
var nocache = 0;
function insert() {
 // Optional: Show a waiting message in the layer with ID login_response
 document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = "Just a second..."
 // Required: verify that all fileds is not empty. Use encodeURI() to solve some issues about character encoding.
    var optionsRadios_god= encodeURI(document.getElementById('optionsRadios_god').value);
    var optionsRadios_tema = encodeURI(document.getElementById('optionsRadios_tema').value);
    // Set te random number to add to URL request
    nocache = Math.random();
    // Pass the login variables like URL variable
    http.open('get', 'insert.php?optionsRadios_god='+optionsRadios_god+'&optionsRadios_tema=' +optionsRadios_tema+'&nocache = '+nocache);
    http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
    http.send(null);
}
function insertReply() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){ 
        var response = http.responseText;
        // else if login is ok show a message: "Site added+ site URL".
        document.getElementById('insert_response').innerHTML = 'Site added:'+ response;
    }
}
```

в конце есть функция insertReply в ней http.responseText мне выдает

Site added: ?>

что не так ?

Comment: Дело в вашем `php` коде. Там знаки `?>` это закрывается `php` код.

Comment: АХАХ смотришь смотришь и ничего не видишь а вот responseTex что должна отдавать?

Comment: То что от сервера придет

Comment: С JS ajax не очень то есть responseText мне выдаст то что я в php файле захочу вывести например через echo что то.